# Run scriptA.js if image's URL is in LIST, run scriptB.js if URL is not in LIST

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome extension to block specific images from Reddit posts depending on some backend computer vision that runs in Python. To save on computation / API calls, I am hoping to have the extension "remember" which image URLs it has "seen" before, and choose whether to make the call to the backend API based on this memory.

I am currently using JavaScript and jQuery to block images in an extension `content.js` script, and curious how others would recommend me: 1) keeping in memory a list of image URLs that have been "seen" before, and 2) checking / referencing this list to decide whether to run `scriptA.js` or `scriptB.js`. (The list of image URLs could get long (10,000+); I am not sure if this is an important consideration.)

Comment: have you looked into localStorage and that whole shebang? seems like you can just append to an array you keep in local Storage, and check against that first to see if you make an api call at all? seems like exactly what you need, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: I have not yet checked into localStorage, but I will give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: okay, so looking more into it. it's rough getting clicked or visited link data other than live recording such. local storage is probably the way to go. but you can't do cross domain stuff. even subdomain stuff... but IFRAMES are an interesting workaround.

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest with a global array in the background script to block URLs directly, no need for a content script. To save the results between browser sessions use chrome.storage API.